# How do i compare 3 numbers in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

i'm a newbie
and I need how to compare 3 numbers in Pascal.

Here is what I tried so far

```
BEGIN
max:=A;
IF B>A THEN max:= B;
IF C>B THEN max:= C;
END;
```

but when I choose, for example, `A = 5 , B=2 , C=4`, the output is 4, but it should be 5. Where is the problem?

I want at the end writeln('The Large Number is ',max);

Comment: sounds like homework ;)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at the Tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour and HowToAsk http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no , it's not. It's just a challenge for myself . at school we do only comapre 2 numbers in Pascal .

Comment: i've already got an answer . 
    BEGIN
    max:=A;
    IF B>A THEN max:= B;
    IF (C>B) and (C>A) THEN max:= C;
    END;

Answer (score 4):

You could do this (you should be comparing with `max`)

```
BEGIN
max:=A;
IF B>max THEN max:= B;
IF C>max THEN max:= C;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must compare with `max` instead of `A` or `B`.
Changing your code in a easy way:

```
BEGIN
  max := A;
  IF B > max
  THEN
     max := B;
  IF C > max
  THEN
     max := C; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, in a somewhat recent Pascal, like Delphi or Free Pascal, using the max function from the MATH unit.

```
result:=max(a,max(b,c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **Max** Function of Pascal

```
PROGRAM MaxProgram;
USES math;
VAR
    num1,num2,num3,maxNum : INTEGER;
BEGIN
    (* Receive the Values *)
    WRITELN('Enter First Number');
    READLN(num1);
    WRITELN('Enter Second Number');
    READLN(num2);
    WRITELN('Enter Third Number');
    READLN(num3);
    (* Using the Max Function *)
    maxNum := max(num1,max(num2,num3));
    (* Display Result *)
    writeln('The Highest number is ', MAXNUM);
END.
```

Comment: How is this different than the [answer by Marco van de Voort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34926849/12695027)?